# how to save listview item as a highlighted item

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, highlight

Below is a screenshot of a listview with sample content from sqlite db, how can i save a listview item as a highlighted item when i tap the highlight button on the right? so everytime i open it, the saved highlighted item is automatically highlighted

[image]

my layout xml

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar2" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
    android:src="@drawable/m1"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView2"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
    android:src="@drawable/m2"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton9"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView2"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
    android:src="@drawable/m3"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton10"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: Just  `highlight` word is highlighted

Answer (score 0):

You should just alter the database table & add a 'highlighted' column to it, then on item click event, save the items highlighted status to database. Every time loading the listView, check the highlighted status in adapter.getView() method.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) i'll try this